# Handle multiple controls methods at once

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a form and I need to change the behaviour of some controls when some actions are given by the user. Since there are many controls to handle, meaning buttons, comboboxes, and others, do you know how I can handle methods for all those without handling one by one? Like a loop or something.

Like, for example, for comboboxes I need to overwrite the drawItem event with some code to change their appearance.

I can't find anything on google.

Comment: winforms? wpf? asp?

Comment: webforms? razor?

Comment: You can create your own class that derives from the desired UI control and then you use at all places your UI control instead of the default one. In the derived class you can implement the desired behaviour.

Comment: winforms. i don't know if that's my case...i'm using the controls given by visual studio, there would be too many controls to change...isn't there a simple way to override their methods just as they are?

Answer (score 1):

I did it, in the end. I set for the many comboboxes the same event handler/method, selecting all the comboboxes and then setting the handler name in the properties/events tab (in my case, in the DrawItem handler).

Then in the code the method comes by default with (object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) so I set:

var combo = sender as ComboBox;

and with it I can generally get or set what I need